# Visual Studio 2022 - Debugger stops after every await in the stack after an exception was thrown

Tags: visual-studio

Since the upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 Community i have a very annoying problem with the debugger.

When an exception is thrown the debugger pauses and shows me the exception. So far so good. ;)

But after that, the debugger goes through the whole stack and stops at every single await in the stack! I know the exception is thrown through the whole stack! Why do i have to stop at every call in the stack?!? Very very annoying! In the current dotnet core app i'm working on i have to press on continue about 12 times until it finally reaches the last call (next.invoke() of the pipeline). This makes me stop the app everytime an exception is thrown and restart it, since this is a lot faster. How can i just let the debugger ignore the whole stack (maybe stop again if there is a rethrow)?

Please help! It drives me crazy. :(

Comment: I've just realized that it is after every await, and not after every method call in the stack. So i've changed the title and edited the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

I not yet have a solution for this, I just wanted to mention that the reason for this behaviour is that each await, in fact, really rethrows the exception.